# Creating a plugin that presents a list of projects as buttons, and opens one when pressed?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm pretty new to creating plugins, and python. I've created a plugin called open_projects that has 10 buttons, and I'd like each button to open up a project when its pressed. The plugin works when opened in QGIS, but I'm not sure how to apply the python logic to make the buttons open a project. So far I've tried this (unsuccessfully):

1. Add QPushButton to the list of imports in open_projects.py:

   ```
   from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
   from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QPushButton
   ```
2. Add a new method:

   ```
   def PushButton1(self):
       from qgis.core import QgsProject
       from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

       project = QgsProject.instance()
       print project.filename

      'c:\project1.qgs'
   ```

I know I'm probably way off!

Answer (score 3):

Nice one! I think all you really needed to add was `project.read(QFileInfo('c:/project1.qgs'))` and then connect your button to this function using `self.dockwidget.name_of_pushButton.clicked.connect(PushButton1)`.

Then repeat this for your 10 other buttons...which could be quite messy. Instead you could use the following which:

- Create a dictionary assigning each pushbutton to a project.
- Create a single function to load these projects depending on the pushbutton clicked.
- Connect each pushbutton to this function.

*Note: I'm assuming you used the **Plugin Builder** as [@Zoltan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/26288/zoltan) mentioned and the plugin uses a dockwidget instead of dialog (otherwise you can replace `dockwidget` with `dlg` in the code).*

---

This is what the main parts of the code looks like, include all imports at the beginning:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt, QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
import resources, qgis
```

Then in the `run(self)` function (`PushButton1` is the object name of the first button etc):

```
def run(self):
    project_dict = {'PushButton1': 'project_1.qgs',
                    'PushButton2': 'project_2.qgs',
                    'PushButton3': 'project_3.qgs',
                    'PushButton4': 'project_4.qgs'}

    def load_project(button):
        qgis.utils.iface.newProject()
        project = project_dict[button.objectName()]
        QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo('path/to/projects/' + project))

    self.dockwidget.PushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: load_project(self.dockwidget.PushButton1))
    self.dockwidget.PushButton2.clicked.connect(lambda: load_project(self.dockwidget.PushButton2))
    self.dockwidget.PushButton3.clicked.connect(lambda: load_project(self.dockwidget.PushButton3))
    self.dockwidget.PushButton4.clicked.connect(lambda: load_project(self.dockwidget.PushButton4))
```

---

I only did this for 4 pushbuttons but you can repeat it for 10.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try plugin builder? It is a plugin which you can install from the menu **Plugins/Manage and istall plugins**. This plugin will create a workable plugin with a dialog box with two buttons (Cancel an OK). Then you should customize the dialog (*.ui file) with Qt Designer. You must install Qt designer, it is not part of the QGIS installer. Finally you should add event handler in your python code what to do when a button pushed.